# Access local host website from Android Device

Tags: asp.net

I have created web services application in asp.net mvc and now need to access it from my Android device connected on same network. This is needed to debug webservies application. I do not have a static IP. The site is running with url http://localhost:27719 but I cannot access localhost from Android device. I researched web and tried below options:
Tried changing website binding information in applicationhost.config file. But I couldn't find my webstie entry in applicationhost file.
I have also tried opening the specific port 27719 in windows firewall. But that isn't working too.
I am able to access website if I host on IIS. But I need to access it when I run from Visual Studio, so that I can debug.
 Please suggest how can I access webservices on my machine from Android device connected to same wifi network.

Comment: You can attach the debugger to IIS, you don't have to use IIS Express. If you're running IIS on the same machine, simply do Attach to Process. If IIS is on another machine, then you'll need to obtain the appropriate version of Visual Studio Remote Debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Could you please suggest how can I do. I have never done this before. Any related link would be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Running IIS on same machine. Sorry to bother but could you advise where I can find Attach to Process option. I looked into project properties and dint find any such option. Thanks for continued help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu at the top of the window in Visual Studio, go to Debug, then Attach to Process (alternatively, press `Control Alt P` on your keyboard). It will ask you which process to attach to. Choose w3wp.exe and press Attach. The debugger will then connect to your site in IIS, and you'll be able to debug when the Android device is connected to the site.

It should be noted that you'll need to provide the IP of the server in the URL on your Android device, not "localhost".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the much needed support. But unfortunately I am not getting w3wp.exe in process list. Actually I am using a work around "ngrok.exe" to access website hosted on IIS to acces from Android device. May be this is the reason I am not getting w3wp.exe option.

Comment: Connect your Android device to the same network (via WiFi) and don't use ngrok. If IIS is running on your device, you should then see w3wp.exe when your site is running. If you can't get your Android device on the same network, then open your firewall up so that the correct port if forwarded to your server, or host your site on a public server (you can get free hosting with Microsoft's Azure, and debug there too).

Comment: I removed ngrok and still unable to see the required option. Seems like I am missing something while setting up website in IIS. However trying now to host on Azure. Will again need your couple of minutes if I am stuck wih Azure option. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for everything. Finally I am able to debug through IIS option. This  was quite a valuable learning. I was struggling from last 5 hours for this. Thanks again for everything.